# Can I use the devxci/mbtci docker image?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, sap, mta, mbt

Our Jenkins instance is based on the ppiper/jenkins-master docker image provided by SAP. This image is intended to be used with the Cx Server life-cycle management.
we are using devxci/mbtci to build SAP Multitarget Applications (MTA). As per the https://hub.docker.com/r/devxci/mbtci , the image has been deprecated.
Can anyone help me to understand is it okay to continue to use this image.

Comment: As long as you are ok using an image 1) which can disappear any time (since it was announced to be removed on 30/09/2021) 2) which is not maintained at all so will not benefit from any possible bugfix 3) which potentially contains security vulnerabilities in the specific installed software or the underlying base image..... you're free to use any image that docker can run.